# LASSO IN PYTHON FOR CLASSIFICATION

Tags: python, classification, lasso-regression

I am studying with LASSO in python with sklearn, but it is incorrect when I run the code for classification data set and the obtained result is only one after 10-fold cross-validation.

Y is binary label with 1 and 2.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV, Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

lasso = Lasso().fit(X,Y)
accs=cross_val_score(lasso, X, Y, scoring=None, cv=10)

print('The results:',accs)


I expect get the ten different results after cross-validation with lasso in python.
```

Answer (score 0):

LASSO is for regression type of machine learning. There are two types: Classification and Regression. Perhaps you should try Random forest classification instead.

Comment: ths, first, I just want to experiment if the lasso with classification data set can get the results. Besides, I hope lasso can conduct feature selection and classification with svm or other methods.